# scipy.optimize.curve_fit doesn't fit

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I want to use curve_fit to do exponential regression, so I can calculate the yearly growth rate of my data.

x is the year, y is assets. If it could fit, the growth-rate should be `exp(b) - 1`. But it returns `(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)` as popt.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
from datetime import datetime
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [2011, 255],
    [2012, 349],
    [2013, 449],
    [2014, 554],
    [2015, 658]
], columns=['x', 'y'])

def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(b * x + c)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, df['x'], df['y'])
print('popt', popt)

df['y1'] = func(df['x'], *popt)
print('df\n', df)

plt.plot(df['x'], df['y'])
plt.plot(df['x'], df['y1'], 'g--',
            label='fit: a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f, c=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.xlabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
popt [1.0 1.0 1.0]
df
       x    y   y1
0  2011  255  inf
1  2012  349  inf
2  2013  449  inf
3  2014  554  inf
4  2015  658  inf
```

[image]

If I change `x` to [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], it could fit.

Answer (score 2):

You are encountering an overflow, since your `x` values are just too large to fit `np.exp(x)` into a 64 bit floating point number, see `np.exp(2015)`. One way to handle this, is to fit the function g(x) = func(x-2011) instead:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015])
y = np.array([255, 349, 449, 554, 658])

def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(b * x + c)

def g(x, a, b, c): 
    return func(x-2011, a, b, c)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(g, x, y)
plt.plot(x, g(x, *popt))
plt.show()
```

Comment: I still do not get the reason. Could you try this? `np.array([1, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015])` with `x-2000` or `x-2011`, the result are quite different. What is the theory for choosing subtraction?

Comment: Basically, the idea is to fit the function g for x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] and then shift it by x = 2011 to the right. However, this only works properly if all your x values are in the same order of magnitude. In your example you will also encounter overflows since `np.exp(1-2000)=np.exp(-1999)=np.exp(1999)**(-1)`. Alternatively, you can do a log-fit, i.e. you fit against np.log(x).

Comment: But it seems that `x-2011` works. `np.exp(2010)` should be bigger than `np.exp(1999)`, right?

Comment: No, it's smaller.

Comment: `np.exp(2010)` overflows too. But it seems `x-2011` works. Actually, `func` uses  `np.exp(b*2010)`, not `np.exp(2010)` directly.